# Matching numbers embedded in a line in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a regular expression in perl that will match this line

```
<sqlpurchSBC comn 23 8313364.B9230352.329 11200.00 SOLD>
```

my expression is this so far but it doesnt seem to match my string

```
m|sqlpurchSBC.*(\d+).(\d+).*(\d+).(\d+).(\d+) SOLD|
```

I am essentially trying to extract the value 23 and also the value 11200.00. The two decimal does not count though. I need help guys. Thanks

Comment: (1)  The `*` quantifier is "_greedy_" -- it matches as much as it possibly can; for a string `hi 1234` the regex `/(.*)(\d)/` captures `hi 123` and `4` (2) The lone period `.` matches any character; need to escape it to match the literal `.` character, so `/\./`

Comment: You can use `split` for a far easier job, `my @nums = (split)[2,-2];` (if the string is in `$_`, or `split ' ', $var`). Then strip decimals if needed (it's unclear in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
m|<sqlpurchSBC.*?(\d+)\s+[\.\w]+\s+(\d+)\.?.*|
                |
          tell .* to be non greedy
```

Comment: I need the SOLD part of the expression to also be matched before I can accept the values detected. How do I include it in this expression?

Comment: I got it. Thanks

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It is concise, accurate, responsive. What is SO becoming?

Comment: @dawg: Not my down vote, but I'd guess that someone doesn't like code-only answers given that I got one too!

Comment: Could be. Personally, a concise code-only answer is preferable to some long winded explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I think a call to `split` would be better here

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $s = '<sqlpurchSBC comn 23 8313364.B9230352.329 11200.00 SOLD>';

my @pair;
@pair = ( split ' ', $s )[2,4] if $s =~ /<sqlpurchSBC.+SOLD>/;

say "@pair";
```

#### output

```
23 11200.00
```